# how to change the row height of datagrid control programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, forms

Hi I want to adjust the row height of datagrid programatically at runtime,
I am using the below code :

```
dgRates.DataSource = dsRates.Tables[0];

foreach (DataGridColumnStyle vColumnStyle in dgRates.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles)
{               
    vColumnStyle.Width = 60;
}
```

But  I am getting the

> "ArgumentOutOfRangeException Parameter
>   name: index".

Please tell me how to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Winforms or ASP.NET? Both tags don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're adjusting the width of the columns, not the height of the rows (or at least, trying to). Rows in a data grid are set globally, using `dg.RowHeight`, or you can set the `Height` property on the `DataGridViewRows` individually.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I got the solution .